# How can I resize my partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

There are a few other questions here with a similar title, I followed the steps in each one but I'm still unable to resize my Ubuntu 11.04 partition using **Gparted**. When I right click on sda1, and choose resize, I am unable to **add** space to the partition, only subtract.

My apologies should this be closed due to being so similar to the other like questions.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing this with a live CD, the drives must be unmounted first.

The unallocated space must be beside the partition you wish to resize. To do this you must move the smaller partition (swap space) to the right.

Comment: I like using the ultimate boot cd: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/
It has a multitude of tools including gparted

Comment: See edit, move smaller partition.

Comment: How do I move it to the right?

Comment: My mistake, I was simply moving the sliders, not the actual "block" itself. Thank you very much! : )

Comment: @Alan: I have a new 11.04 install, and thus no GParted,but in previous versions there is a "resize/ move" button. I would Google for "move partition gparted" and look at some results. Hope this helps. Will.

Comment: @JavaNut13 - if you want it back do `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Comment: You do not need to move the swap partition. just delete it, resize root partition (leaving space for swap) then create the new swap partition.

Comment: @Cas - yes that'll also work. Probably what I'd do here.