# How to edit the disk partition?

Tags: disk

When I installed **Ubuntu** I had already **windows 7** in my computer and I installed **Ubuntu** aside **windows 7**, but when I did the disk partition I did it the opposite of what I wanted (I mean I give Ubuntu 500G and windows 7 200G but what I wanted actully is the opposite)

Is there any way to edit disk partition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resize my partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38246/how-can-i-resize-my-partition)

Answer (score 1):

> `gparted` is a great partitioning tool - I have used it to resize FAT, NTFS, EXT[2..4] and haven't run into any issues as of yet. However - with all disk operations there is always the possibility of failure and that should always be weighed during resizing.
>
> Make sure you have nothing mounted to the drives you're attempting to resize, ensure that you have ample CPU and RAM to perform the operations. If you're on a Laptop make sure it's plugged in and that it won't suspend or hibernate while performing these operations. Lastly this can be time intensive - my last tip is, while gparted is running it may appear unresponsive or frozen. Just let it finish.

from: [Is GParted a good tool for resizing an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1813/is-gparted-a-good-tool-for-resizing-an-ntfs-partition)

You may want to read this: **[Resize Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition)** and [How to resize Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions)

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with command line tool then this would be usefull.

Usr fdisk command with proper knowledge of disk partition.[disk uses link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html)

or refer man page of fdisk [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man8/fdisk.8.html) 
and make