# Can't make all my changes to partitions at once with gparted

Tags: 18.04, gparted

Like the title says, I can't fill/expand my nvme0n1p5 with the unallocated space.

[image]

Comment: You need to boot Ubuntu from the Live USB/DVD and select Try Ubuntu without Installing. You can't modify the Ubuntu System partition that is running. Its like trying to change the tire of a car when you are driving it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resize my partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38246/how-can-i-resize-my-partition)

Comment: The suggested dup does not explain how to expand a partition on the left, only the (easy) right.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not see the key icon, you can modify a partition. The corollary is, you can't modify partitions while in use (the key icon).

[image: Show key icon]

You need to modify the partitions from outside the system; a Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, et al., LiveUSB will suffice. Boot from the Live USB then launch [gParted](https://gparted.org). <-- Click for more detail.

Space you expand into must be adjacent.

With gparted, you define a change, then click on the green check mark above the bar graph, under the word **Partition**, to commit the change.

[image: Show the COMMIT check mark]

Do you see the pending changes to /dev/nvme0n1p3 and /dev/nvme0n1p2 in the bottom pane? Those are waiting for you to click on the check mark to be actually made.

[image: Changes queued up to be committed]

Overlapping changes can't be made; you can't expand or move into space used by an existing partition, and must delete or shift that partition before its space becomes available. So, with gparted, often it's make a change-commit the change, make another change-commit the change; lather, rinse; repeat.

The [gnome-disks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-disks.1.html) GUI app, Disks, works differently; when you define a change, you also make it.  I like gparted better because it's more difficult to make a change which loses your data (not *impossible*, mind you, just more difficult).